# How to validate row if it's compliant before pushing it to pgsql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, validation

Say table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    enter_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    comment TEXT
);
```

Now in python, say I get data like this:

```
foo_user = {"id": 123, "enter_time": None, "comment": ''}
```

How can I manually validate this data before sending this to pgsql?

Is there any library which already do this by pulling schema information from pgsql and doing validation on that?

Comment: What's wrong with catching the possible exception from the INSERT statement?

Comment: @Sebastian so basically I have no control over the library that throws the message to msg bus and then to db, so it's quiet important to validate the data before handover the data, sorry for simplicity I didn't mentioned it

Comment: You could use any validation library out there such as `marshmallow` or `pydantic`.

Comment: Well then, create a shadow of table foo `create table foo_shadow (like foo including constraints)` and try to insert into it (begin - insert - rollback, looking for exceptions of course) before calling your library code.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm yeah that's one way to do, but there's lots of table over 300 .. I was thinking if there's a way to pull schema from pgsql and validate against that

Comment: So you need a query which returns column names and types of a table?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy yes, against that I can validate the rows

Comment: maybe database transaction should be ok.when you update or insert data in transaction.it do nothing affect on table before you commit.if validate error,you can rollback

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to retrieve the expected data type from the DB itself, this can be accomplished, as suggested by @gaurav) using a:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns where ...
```

This gives to you the type schema, this can be used as 'validation schema'

#### simple example - diy

Here a simple example limited to check if input data can be typed (it will be casted by postgres in the same manner, maybe)

```
from datetime import datetime
schema = {"id": "integer", "enter_time": "TIMESTAMP", "comment": 'text'}

def is_valid(v, validator):
    # dummy validator, we try to apply a constructor
    # returns only True/False, 
    # If False... we don't know why!
    # here you can use a RE for check if input is syntactically correct
    try:
        validator(v)
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    


# type to validator
binding = {'integer':int,
           'TIMESTAMP': datetime.fromtimestamp,
           'text':str}

#validation schemaa
val_schema = {k:binding[v] for k,v in schema.items()}



foo_user = {"id": 123, "enter_time": None, "comment": ''}

for k,v in foo_user.items():
    print (k, ':', is_valid(v, val_schema[k]))


# 
# id : True
# enter_time : False
# comment : True
```

#### better approach

For the second step, there are specialized validation libraries, they can do typing, clipping, and schema validation (like 2 fields password that must be identical) and a lot of useful stuff.

I've worked a lot with [voluptuous](https://pypi.org/project/voluptuous/) but [many choices](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/top-5-python-data-validation-library/) are available up to now, do a good survey before adopt one of that library in your lib stack.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns "mytable1" column names,their types and default values

```
 SELECT attname 
      ,pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as Datatype 
      ,coalesce(d.adsrc,'') AS default_value
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid, a.attnum)=(d.adrelid,d.adnum)
 WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
   AND a.attrelid = ( SELECT c.oid
                       FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
                       LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
                      WHERE c.relname = 'mytable1' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add ORM there are a couple of ways to retrieve your schema.

Automap from SQLAlchemy:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html

It will map your schema to classes and then you will be able to use this mapping to insert your data.

There is also this package https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/ which generates the tables as classes in the codebase.

If you are looking to extract info from DB directly regarding columns PostgreSQL information_schema columns table holds this data.
For example:

```
SELECT  
  column_name,
  ordinal_position,
  column_default,
  is_generated,
  is_nullable,
  data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test';
```

Or for a complete schema

```
SELECT  
   column_name,
   ordinal_position,
   column_default,
   is_generated,
   is_nullable,
   data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  table_schema='test';
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am correctly understand this then you want schema of table so you match with current input before inserting to database. if yes then

```
cur.execute("SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'foo';")
print(dict(cur.fetchall()))
#{"id": "integer", "enter_time": "TIMESTAMP", "comment": 'text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use ORMs. SQLAlchemy is used by many.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pydantic`, you could validate inputs as:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class FooModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    enter_time: datetime
    comment: str

    @validator('id')
    def id_cannot_be_none(cls, v):
        if v is None:
            raise ValueError('id can not be None')
        return v
    
    @validator('enter_time')
    def enter_time_cannot_be_none(cls, v):
        if v is None:
            raise ValueError('enter_time can not be None')
        return v

# validate inputs 
foo_user = {"id": 123, "enter_time": None, "comment": ''}

validate_foo_user = FooModel(**foo_user)
```

NB: we might need timestamp type hint instead of datetime